# Buffer overflow: How is it actually implemented in a pen testing environment?

Tags: penetration-test, buffer-overflow

**Background:**

So when exploiting a Buffer Overflow vulnerability, the attacker needs to
 not only generate the payload (Let's say to create a binding shell), but also set up the corrupted buffer with the said payload to be sent to the victim's machine. (ie. a tcp echo server that utilizes a vulnerable BoF function call  that is running on Windows XP OS). And as part of setting up the buffer, there needs to be certain parameters taken from the victim's machine; such as

- the EIP offset at the moment of the crash
- the memory location of the corrupted EIP (pointing at the payload to
  be executed).

**My Question is:**

*In a professional pen testing environment how would the pen tester access the above two parameters without having access to the victim's machine?* Meaning without having to install a disassembler and debugger inside the victim PC and actually analyze the program in the debugger.

*Is there another way to simulate this attack without having access to the victim's machine?*

Comment: Are you basically asking how a buffer overflow can be done remotely?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I meant in the question =]

Comment: A copy of the software on their own machine they can use to fuzz and debug crashes

Comment: Obtained by some social engineering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the times you'll have to emulate the target's system and develop your exploit locally. About how to learn about the target's system, that has to do with the *enumeration* process. Of course depending on the binary you're trying to exploit, it may be possible to achieve an information leakage, and in that way you'll be able to make your exploit work even remotely even if your system is a bit different from the target's system (*of course if your target uses e.g. linux you'll have to use linux also, but not the exact version*).

For example, in case of a *format string* vulnerability you may be able to leak libc remotely. But there are other cases also, for example if the binary uses a *string writing function*, like `puts` (*or printf etc...*), it may be possible to use that function to leak libc base address from a GOT entry in runtime so you can construct a multi-stage exploit that bypasses even aslr. Now about how you can compute libc base address from a leak, there many ways (*you can either use [**libc database**](https://github.com/niklasb/libc-database) or a web wrapper of libc-database [**here**](https://github.com/blukat29/search-libc) etc...*).

Comment: I see, so can one calculate the EIP offset and the corrupted EIP memory location (of JMP ESP instruction for example) from the said information leak (libc base address) ?

Comment: yes almost, EIP offset _depends on the binary_ and doesn't have to do anything with libc, but JMP ESP and other gadgets will probably (if they are part of the binary) depend on libc base address, so the important thing here is that even if aslr is enabled your exploit will still be working!

Comment: @gameOver, thank you for the explanation. So technically without a copy of the binary we are trying to exploit, it would be very difficult to obtain the EIP offset or even the JMP ESP instruction memory when the libc base address is leaked?

Comment: and best way to administer this attack is to actually have a copy of the vulnerable binary?

Comment: yes of course, without the binary you will probably not be able to determine EIP offset to craft your exploit, but in case you have the binary then your exploit will be more "system-independent".